How can I directly authorize all YouTube channels under a Google account?
I need to access YouTube account data and analysis reports through my website. However, if a Google account has multiple YouTube channels, let's say 10 channels, do I have to authorize each one individually, or is there a way to authorize all channels at once by default, so I can view the analysis reports for all channels under the Google account?
Authorizing each channel one by one is too time-consuming.
I would appreciate it if anyone who has implemented this feature or knows how it works could share their methods.
